# Regex: Don't extract optional token

Tags: regex

I want to extract words from a sentence like this:

```
I want to (?P<activity>([a-zäöüß\s]+?)+)
I want to have a beer 
-> activity: have a beer
```

Now, I want to have something optional at the end of the sentence:

```
I want to (?P<activity>([a-zäöüß\s]+?)+)(?: with my friends)?
I want to have a beer with my friends
-> have a beer with my friends
```

How do I have to change my regex so that `with my friends` will not be included in the activity?

Answer (score 0):

If you know nothing else will come after "with my firends", you could try a non-greedy quantifier and match end of sentence:

```
I want to (?P<activity>([a-zäöüß\s]+?)+?)(?: with my friends)?$
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/MG4Ga5/1

Otherwise, maybe you can use a lookahead:

```
I want to(?P<activity>((?= with my friends)|(\s[a-zäöüß]+))+)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/MG4Ga5/2

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which checks if what follows is either `with my friends` or the end of the line `$` if you want to make it optional.

[`I want to (?P<activity>[a-zäöüß\s]+?)(?= with my friends|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/Sd1WFC/1)

**Explanation**

- Match `I want to`
- Match in a named capture group called activity `(?P<activity>`
- Your character set one or more times `[a-zäöüß\s]+`
- Make it non greedy `?`
- Close the named capture group `)`
- Asserting that what follows is `with my friends` or the end of the line `(?= with my friends|$)`